# Order of Sprite transformations in libgdx

Tags: libgdx, sprite

I want to do the following:

[image]

which is

1. apply the rotation
2. and then, resize the Sprite

But since Sprite transformations have a predefined order, this is what happens:

[image]

1. resize the Sprite
2. rotate it

So, my question is, is there any way to do it?

If you take a look at the API docs, it says...

`Sets the size of the sprite when drawn, before scaling and rotation are applied.`

So I guess the only way to do it is modifying manually the vertices? Or am I wrong? Any better way?

Comment: Yes, you must manually adjust the individual vertices. You can subclass the Sprite class to do it. It will probably look distorted since there are only four vertices in a typical sprite (try working out the geometry...for some angles there's no way to make it look like your picture no matter where you put the four vertices). An alternative would be to draw the rotated version to a FrameBuffer and then draw the output as a scaled texture region. You could draw a bunch of them to a FrameBuffer and create texture regions out of them.

Comment: @Tenfour04 that's true, I totally forgot about FBOs. If you write it in a good answer I'll accept it ;)